# Как использовать одну и ту же переменную в разных JS функциях?

Tags: javascript

Если в одной функции есть определение переменной через `var`, к примеру:

```
var company =  user.attributes.company;
```

то как в другой функции использовать эту же переменную?

Пример, который не работает:

```
function login() {
    var company =  user.attributes.company;
}

function test() {
    var test = company;
}
```

Что нужно исправить?

Comment: Поместите определение второй функции внутрь первой функции.:)

Comment: Там не получиться. Там сложный вызов идет, нужно решение именно как получать из другой функции

Comment: @arthru, немного переформулировал ваш вопрос. Правильно ли я передал вашу основную мысль?

Comment: не силен в js, но все-таки: нельзя ли вернуть нужную переменную с помощью **return**, а затем ее использовать там, где нужно?

Comment: @Александр  Товарищ не ищет простых путей!:)

Comment: еще, что первое приходит в голову, передавать значение как параметр функции, либо объявить переменную глобальной, если такое есть в js

Answer (score 2):

Похоже, что вы не до конца понимаете, как работают контексты видимости (scope) в JavaScript.

Если определить код в теге `<script>`, то он будет выполнятся в *глобальном контексте*. Например:

```
<script "type=text/javascript">
    // Это глобальный контекст выполнения
</script>
```

Определение каждой функции создает новый контекст видимости - *локальный контекст*.

Ключевое слово `var` используется для объявления переменной в текущем контексте видимости. Кроме того, эта переменная так же будет доступна во всех вложенных контекстах (для них она будет глобальной), но недоступна в контексте более высокого уровня:

```
var test = function() {
    var a = 'local variable';

    var testLocal = function() {
        // Переменная "a" в этом контексте не объявляется.
        // Используется переменная из контекста более
        // высокого уровня.
        return a;
    };

    return testLocal();
}

console.log(a); // undefined
console.log(test()); // 'local variable'
```

Теперь о вашем конкретном случае. По всей видимости, вы хотите использовать одну и туже переменную в двух независимых функциях. Для этого достаточно объявить ее в контексте более высокого уровня:

```
// Переменная company будет доступна для всех вложенных
// контекстов видимости.
var company;

function login() {
    // Обратите внимание, здесь нет ключевого слова "var",
    // потому что используется "глобальная" переменная.
    company =  user.attributes.company;
}

function test() {
    // Локальной переменной test присваивается значение
    // "глобальной" переменной company.
    var test = company;
}
```

**Замечание:**

По-хорошему, вы не должны определять лишних переменных в *глобальном контексте* выполнения. Это связано с потенциальными конфликтами и проблемами переопределения значений. Хорошей практикой является создание немедленно вызываемой функции, ограничивающей область видимости для ваших "глобальных" переменных. А делается это так:

```
(function() {
    var company;

    function login() {        
        // ...
    };

    function test() {        
        // ...
    };
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то вижу два варианта:

I. когда вторая ф-я вызывается из первой, то передавать значение параметром:

```
function login() {
    var company =  user.attributes.company;
    test(company);
}

function test(c) {
    var test = c;
}
```

II. более общее решение – определять эту переменную через уровень выше:

```
var global; // плохая практика
function login() {
    var company =  user.attributes.company;
    global = company;
}

function test() {
    var test = global;
}
```

II.**b**. ("**b**aad" – *совсем плохая практика, ужос-ужос*). Убрать `var` перед `company` – это так же сделает переменную глобальной.

Comment: А ещё можно построить статическую переменную.

Comment: @LEQADA напишите, как – самостоятельным ответом, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Sergiks, в node.js переменная `global` - это [одна из встроенных](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global) глобальных переменных. А поскольку контекст выполнения не указан в вопросе, это имя лучше не использовать.

Comment: Спасибо за разумное уточнение. Хотя в данном вопросе, скорее всего, nodejs не используется, в общем полезно знать.

Answer (score 0):

Можно поместить определение второй функции внутрь первой функции. Например

```
<!DOCTYPE html />

<html lang = "en">

<body>

    <script>
        var fn;

        function login() {
            var company = "My Company";
            function test() {
                var test = company;
                alert(test);
            }
            fn = test;
        }

        login();
        fn();
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```